# How to use the Azure Front Door hostname as domain name for the backend website hosted on Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm, azure-front-door, azure-dns

We have a solution with Azure Front Door then an Application Gateway with a Virtual Machine as the back-end. We would like to use the Azure Front Door 'Frontend host' *.azurefd.net also as domainname/hostname of the website running on the VM.

If we now go to the hostname of the Azure Front Door service we are redirected to the IP address of the VM. The website is displayed correctly, only the website address is the ip address of the VM. We would like to see the *.azurefd.net address, is this possible?

The website is an intranet so the azurefd.net address is not a problem.

Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is how Azure Frond Door works. It either forwards or redirects traffic to publicly resolvable DNS. If you use redirect configuration in Front Door, then it is normal to see your VM IP because is redirecting traffic to VM IP with 3xx HTTP code in your browser. Also If you check your Front Door hostname IP address you should see one of the public IP that belongs to the subnet which is listed in Azure IP Ranges depends on your region. Check which subnet that your regions allocate with the below command.

```
az network list-service-tags --location
```

Or check the [list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519)